# use contains on a integer column with python peewee and postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, peewee

In my postgresql database there is a table which has a column with an integer data type. I would like to perform a .contains operation using the peewee python orm.

It does not seem to work since the integer value needs to be converted to a string before the comparison can happen. In postgresql you can do value::text and then the integer value will be a string and you can use it in a like expression.

Can i do this using the peewee orm, convert the value first and then use .contains? Or maybe there is another way?

For example i would like to match 20 out of 2022022

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple answers, but I'll just add my own .02 as the developer of the library.

```
from playhouse.shortcuts import cast

query.where(cast(Url.http_status_code, 'text').contains(search_val))
```

I'm not sure which is more performant (probably TO_CHAR), but just in case you were looking for something more generic, you can use `cast`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def python_partial_match(needle,key,haystack):
     for item in haystack.select():
         if needle in str(getattr(item,key,None)): 
            yield item

for result in python_partial_match("20","phone_number",UserModelClass):
    print "GOT RESULT:",result
```

but its going to be really slow for big data sets I think

alternatively i think you can do something like

```
PostgresqlDatabase.register_ops({'::', '::'})

@Node.extend()
def cast(self, as_type):
    return Expression(self, '::', SQL(as_type))

DataModel.select().where(DataModel.integer_col.cast('str').contains("20"))
```

maybe... i didnt test that cast thing ...  (see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=cast#Node.extend)

actually it looks like there is a builtin `cast` in the playhouse for postgres see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=cast#cast

Comment: unfortunately these suggestions did not work for me, but i did find a way

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it. I also tested coleifer's solution above and it works great. 
I ended up using the postgresql formatting functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html

```
query.where(fn.TO_CHAR(Url.http_status_code, '999').contains(search_val))
```